# A random bit string chances of ending or starting with a 0 and chance of a 0 being a digit?

Tags: probability

> (a) A computer program produces random bit strings of length 8.
>   Calculate the probability of the following:
>
> (i) A bit string contains no zeros.
>
> (ii) A bit string either starts or ends with a zero

(i) There are 8 numbers which can be either 0/1
so the can

$2^8$ chances of being at least one zero 1/256

(ii)
$2^2$ which equals 1/4 either it starts with a 0 or ends with a 0

I would like to  know if I have gone the right way about solving these problems?

Comment: $0$ has $100\%$ chances of being a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going the right way with (i) if we may assume that the probability of having a 0 or 1 is always 1/2, and that the numbers are generated independently. Then:
(i) 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{ no zeros }) = \mathbb{P}( \text{ only ones }) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 
\frac{1}{2} \dots \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^8} = 1/256.
\end{align*}
(ii) is however a bit different:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{ ends or starts with 0 }) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}( \text{ does not start with 0 and not end with 0}) \\ &= 1 - \mathbb{P}( \text{ starts and ends with 1 }) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^8=256$ possible strings of $8$ bits. Only "$11111111$" contains no zero.

> $\dfrac1{256}$.

Excluding the middle digits which play no role, there are $2^2=4$ possible strings of $2$ bits. Only "$11$" contains no zero.

> $1-\dfrac14$.